Showing that E-schemes are TVD
I'm attempting Exercise 12.2 in Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems by R.J Leveque, which claims that E-schemes are TVD. It hints to use Harten's theorem, but I am unable to formulate the $D_i$ that works.
For context, in solving a non-linear hyperbolic problem $q_t+f(q)q_x=0$, an E-scheme has a numerical flux $F_{i+1/2}$ such that $sign(Q_{i+1}-Q_i)[F_{i+1/2}-f(q)]\leq 0 $ for all $q$ between $Q_i$ and $Q_{i+1}$.
It hints to use $C_{i-1}=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}[\frac{f(Q_{i-1}-F_{i-1/2}}{Q_i-Q_{i-1}}]$, but I cannot formualte the $D_i$ that would work. Would appreciate any help!
